# How To uninstall Ubuntu 13.10 from pc having no other OS and Install Windows 8.1?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I had windows 7 in C drive and windows 8.1 in D drive. But I installed Ubuntu 13.10 and the system got formatted. I wanted to have 3 OS. But lost the other two. I didnt make any partitions.Now I want to uninstall Ubuntu and install windows 8.1, How to do it?>
P.S : I dont know much about partioning.

Comment: Plus this is not an Ubuntu problem: you need to do this from the **Windows installation media**.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows-8.1 installation disc with you format the ubuntu partition using  ntfs with it.

After that install windows-8 on that partition. May be if you can clarify me more like

1.Which drive got formatted.

2.Installed via WUBI installer or direct etc

Then I can help you more

Also if u need 3 OS then you need to have 3 partitions in your hard-drive Every partition for separate OS.

If you don't Want to do it then It can also be done in 2 partitions Install Ubuntu Inside  windows via WUBI installer.